# Ubuntu Upgrade Error // Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server-10.3 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.32+maria~bionic) but 1:10.3.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 mariadb-server-core-10.3 : Breaks: mariadb-client-10.3 (< 1:10.3.32+maria~bionic) but 1:10.3.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Check your sources; your paste shows *bionic* or 18.04 packages, yet you stated you're using *focal* or 20.04.  Package problems can be expected if you use packages created for a different OS/release.

Comment: Related: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)